# Error in adding new object to Data Model diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am unable to drag in new elements (e.g. sql table, view, query, database connection...) into my UML diagram for sparks EA. I was able to do this until the other day & get the following error:
[image: get the following error:]

It seems like something to do with the session id or something..?
Also noticed that a lot of the logos are now the same grey "<>" , when before they were all different

[image: (see here)]

Comment: You need to enable to appropriate MDG (can't test at the moment, so I can't tell which)

Comment: @qwerty_so Seems like it's more than that. If the MDG is not enabled he wouldn't be abel to see the toolbox either I think. Definitely weird, but not something that has an easy answer I'm afraid. Needs a fair bit of troubleshooting to figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Since EAUML is one of the system MDGs in the program folder that might have gone corrupted.

Comment: What does the Specialize/Manage-Tech say? Is Core Extenstions enabled? That's where EAUML is placed.